# Adding a column to a Multiindex Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to add a column SUM to the df1 below. It's a Datetime MultiIndex and the new column SUM should return the sum of the price
row.

```
multex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['price',
 'weight','quantity','portfolio'] ,df1.index],names=['Date', 'Stats'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=multex, columns= df1.columns.values.tolist())
```

Subsequently would like to add a row SUM as well that returns the same value. I've tried the following so far:

```
df1['SUM']= df1.ix['price'].sum(axis=1) 


                           A      B      C        D     E

2006-04-28 00:00:00                                    
            price        69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
            weight
            std
2006-05-01 00:00:00  
            price         71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
            weight
            std
2006-05-02 00:00:00   
            price        72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
            weight
            std
```

Comment: I would update your question so people can easily reproduce your dataframe.  Also, what was the result of `df1['SUM']= df1.ix['price'].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: HI. thanks. thats the error that I get: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2939,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2939,2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use first [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), because error:

> KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Then use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
df1 = df1.sort_index()

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1['SUM'] = df1.loc[idx[:,'price'],:].sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
                                A      B      C      D      E      SUM
Date                Stats                                             
2006-04-28 00:00:00 price   69.62  69.62  6.518  65.09  69.62  280.468
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
2006-05-01 00:00:00 price   71.50  71.50  6.522  65.16  71.50  286.182
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
2006-05-02 00:00:00 price   72.34  72.34  6.669  66.55  72.34  290.239
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
```

---

```
df1['SUM'] = df1.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')),:].sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
                                A      B      C      D      E      SUM
Date                Stats                                             
2006-04-28 00:00:00 price   69.62  69.62  6.518  65.09  69.62  280.468
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
2006-05-01 00:00:00 price   71.50  71.50  6.522  65.16  71.50  286.182
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
2006-05-02 00:00:00 price   72.34  72.34  6.669  66.55  72.34  290.239
                    std       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
                    weight    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      NaN
```

Comment: perfect! thnk you!

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: can i ask one las thing? what if you wanted to add the 'Sum' as a row in the second multiindex level, as opposed to as a column? I added 'Sum' in the multiindex above in my question but I have trouble coming up with the proper adjustment to your formula.thanks

Comment: Give me a sec, it seems not so easy.

Comment: Do you need `df1.loc[('', 'SUM'),:] = df1.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')),:].sum()` ?

Comment: i get this: `pandas.tslib.DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: price`

Comment: And what about `df1.loc[(None, 'SUM'),:] = df1.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')),:].sum()` ?

Comment: thanks; I get the same error actually. maybe we need to add the SUM to the multiindex as well first?

Comment: interesting, for me it works nice. What is your pandas version? `print pd.show_versions()` ?

Comment: i have the pandas: 0.18.0

Comment: Is possible upgdrade to last?  `0.18.1`. Or another solution can be concating.

Comment: `df2 = df1.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')),:].sum().to_frame().T`
`df2.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([None,'Sum'])`
`print (pd.concat([df1,df2]))`

Comment: it didn't work i guess i won't add that row but it's ok. but i will try upgrading my version;  thanks anyways!

Comment: For me works all ways. But maybe problem is with data. - tey are different as in sample.

Comment: actually it's a sample of the same data. i added the column it looks nice.thanks again